# Android Instant Apps - Cannot Find Symbol From Base Feature Asset

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have a base feature module, and a feature module (you could call it the "child").  The **base** feature module has a strings.xml file asset containing:

```
<resources>
   <string name="app_string">Test String</string>
</resources>
```

I attempt to reference this string resource in the "child" feature's activity, as below:

```
int resId = R.string.app_string;
```

Android Studio appears to respect this reference, and will even direct me to the `app_string` resource when I click it.  However, during compilation, I am met with the following error message:

```
Error:(13, 25) error: cannot find symbol variable app_string
```

The build Gradle file for my "child" feature has the dependency too:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation project(':base')
}
```

I also tried `compile project(':base')`, but no success.

Is there something blatant that I am missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your base and child modules have different package names - let's say they are `com.example.base` and `com.example.child`. Each contains its own set of resources, and their identifiers will be collected in separate R packages:

- `com.example.base.R`
- `com.example.child.R`

Because you're trying to access a resource defined in base module, you need to reference it with the fully qualified name of the variable, which is `com.example.base.R.string.app_string`.

Comment: I attempted that, but unfortunately I'm getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`.  If I were to use the packages you listed, I would be trying:
`int resId = com.example.base.R.string.app_string` as you said.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, I solved it using `com.example.R.string.app_string` (note, I left out the `base` directory in that path)