# Instant App modularization

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-instant-apps, build-tools

I've been working on instant app for a few days. I didn't get it compiled yet.

The project is split into `instant`, `installed`, `base`, `export`, `preview` as features.

In `export` module relies on some layouts, string resources from the `base` module. Then `installed` will compile `base` and `export` module. Everything just works

However, in `preview` does the same thing like some layouts, string resources from the `base` module. Both `export` and `preview` do different things but use the same resources. `instant` module will compile `base`, `preview` but get an error below

```
Unresolved reference: id
Unresolved reference: layout
Unresolved reference: anim
```

Is that a expected behavior from build tool, or a bug from build tool?

Answer (score 2):

When building an instant app, the feature module's R class doesn't contain resource identifiers from the base feature. For all resources that come via the base feature, you should change the import to the base feature R class. (base.R instead of preview.R)

Comment: Your answer really helps. On a side node, the build tool still generates resource identifiers from the `base` module for the `feature` module.

Comment: If your issue is as Hassan describes, then please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688018/android-instant-apps-cannot-find-symbol-from-base-feature-asset